How to run typescript command in vscode tasks?
Can't run a command in tasks for current file:
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "the task", 
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "${command:typescript.organizeImports}",
    },
  ]
}

I get an error:
TypeScript Server Error (5.6.3)
scriptInfo.isOrphan is not a function
TypeError: scriptInfo.isOrphan is not a function
    at _ProjectService.tryGetDefaultProjectForFile (/Users/user_name/Documents/project_name/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:186446:38)
    at _ProjectService.tryGetDefaultProjectForEnsuringConfiguredProjectForFile (/Users/user_name/Documents/project_name/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:186465:17)
    at _ProjectService.ensureDefaultProjectForFile (/Users/user_name/Documents/project_name/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:186469:17)
    at IpcIOSession.getFileAndProjectWorker (/Users/user_name/Documents/project_name/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:191719:77)
    at IpcIOSession.getFileAndProject (/Users/user_name/Documents/project_name/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:191705:17)
    at IpcIOSession.organizeImports (/Users/user_name/Documents/project_name/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:192284:36)
    at organizeImports (/Users/user_name/Documents/project_name/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:190451:43)
    at /Users/user_name/Documents/project_name/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:192651:15
    at IpcIOSession.executeWithRequestId (/Users/user_name/Documents/project_name/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:192640:14)
    at IpcIOSession.executeCommand (/Users/user_name/Documents/project_name/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:192649:29)
    at IpcIOSession.onMessage (/Users/user_name/Documents/project_name/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:192697:68)
    at process.<anonymous> (/Users/user_name/Documents/project_name/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserver.js:525:14)
    at process.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at emit (node:internal/child_process:937:14)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)

Maybe it needs to specify

the directory of the current project,
the path to the 'tsconfig.json' file,
or pass the current open file as arguments to the command?

Please help me what am I doing wrong?

without VSC how would you run that in a shell

@rioV8 I understood you. It's reasonable. And yet, is it possible to run a typescript command via tasks?

what if you use the ${command:typescript.organizeImports} in an ${input} variable and use that result in an echo shell command

@rioV8 Good idea, but "Cannot substitute input variable 'organizeImports' because command 'typescript.organizeImports' did not return a result of type string". If you have any ideas on how to get around this, I'd appreciate it. Well, for now I've done it using "runCommands" in "keybindings" file.

As a workaround, I solved the issue in the "keybindings.json" file:
  { 
    "key": "alt+i",
    "command": "runCommands",
    "args": {
      "commands": [
        "typescript.organizeImports",
        "typescript.removeUnusedImports",
        "workbench.action.files.save",
        {
          "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
          "args": "clear_imports"
        }
      ]
    }
  },

